# What is the convention for the @return tag if the method is overriding and returning parent's method's result?

Tags: php, documentation, convention

If I have a method in some class that returns a boolean for example

```
class A {
  /**
   * This method doesn't do much
   * @return boolean
   **/
  public function a() {
    // Do something 
    // ... 

    return true;
  }
}
```

And then I have another method that overrides this one, and then calls the parent and returns the parent's result:

```
class B extends A {
  /**
   * @Override
   * This method just does some extra work, before handing
   * it over to class A's method 
   * @return what? 
   **/
  public function a() {
    // Do some extra stuff 
    // ... 

    // Then hand it over to the parent 
    return parent::a();
  }
}
```

What would be the best (conventional) thing to list as `B::a()`'s return value? Should it say that it returns `boolean`, or that it returns "the parent's value", and refer to the parent for documentation? Or something else?

From a writing point of view, the second one seems more reasonable, as, if the parent's return value changes, it will not imply changes in other parts of the documentation. From a reading point of view, the first one seems more convenient just to get your answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is up to you or your team :)

So - it is OK to write

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
```

for class B, or you can just use next tag:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
```

What is means that method has same description as parent.
http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.inlineinheritdoc.pkg.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no point to have a function a() in B

```
public function a() {
    // Do some extra stuff 
    // ... 

    // Then hand it over to the parent 
    return parent::a();
}
```

Because when there is a instance of B,it actually has a function a() which refers to it's parent's method a().

By the way,when you define a function which override it's parent's method,you'd better offer your documentation in it's docblock.Because you may have a different return or do something else in it.

Comment: There is a lot of point to it, because if class A has a `save()` method that does some generic data saving, but B needs some very specific data validation, then that's going to be defined in `B::save()` (thus the "extra stuff" comment). Which is just one of a million examples.

Comment: @ImNotMike I mean,if you do the same thing,then you don't need to do it in child class.

Comment: I understand that, that's why I'm mentioning the "extra stuff" comment in there, that's why it exists - to indicate that there is more than just the same stuff going on.

Comment: @ImNotMike then you'd better add documentation separately.

Comment: @ImNotMike well,I have to mention,if your implementation do the save work within it's parent's implementation except for the "extra stuff",then use `/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */ `Vladimir Gilevich have said in his answer.They should have the same documentation if they have same effect.